# Whitespaces with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with a line that looks like this:

```
string    = "test, test1, test2";
```

Between the "string" and the "=" are some whitespaces, the amount of whitespaces can vary. How can  I check, if the line contains the word "string" and the "=" and that between the "string" and the "=" are only whitespaces?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition checking in regex would be done using lookahead,

```
(?=^.*?\bstring\s+=)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iA1yO5/5)

Regex engine sets the matching marker at the start of the line which contains `string` followed by one or more spaces and again followed by a `=` symbol.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Would you mind explaining the reason to use a lookahead here?

Comment: "Condition checking in regex would be done using lookahead". See the demo link, the first two lines matches the condition so the marker is present just at the begining of those two lines.

Comment: @AvinashRaj If I only want to match a string against a simple regex, does the lookahead add any value?

Comment: no, it wont....I posted this because op mention `How can I check, if the line contains the word "string" and the "=" `

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
^string\s*=
```

Where `^` means beginning of line, `\s` any type of whitespace and `*` any number of times (including zero, if that's not desirable use `+` instead).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
\bstring\s+=
```

- `\bstring` to match literal `string` where `\b` is word boundary
- `\s+` to match one or more whitespaces
- `=` to match literal `=`

Comment: Note that this will match things like `any other string = ...`.

Comment: OP never wrote that string will start with `string` literal.